# How can I update a component in a GUI and then have it sleep.

Tags: java, swing, timer, jframe, actionlistener

I feel like I have searched everywhere. I believe I know the reason that my code doesn't work but do not quite understand it or how to fix my problem. Initially I tried using the TimeUnit import and Thread.sleep() and both of those updated the JFrame after waiting the given seconds. I want to have the JFrame display the results of the game, wait a couple of seconds and then have the results be hidden again.

From what I have read, using the import javax.swing.Timer is the direction I need to be heading in but for the life of me I can not figure out how to implement it into my code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

//////////////Below is what I believe to be the part of the code that needs to be edited/////////////////

```
btnStay.addActionListener(l -> {
        //System.out.println("btnStay was pressed");
        btnStay.setEnabled(false);
        btnHit.setEnabled(false);
        btnConfirm.setVisible(false);
        lblAccount.setVisible(false);
        lblBet.setVisible(false);
        txtAccount.setVisible(false);
        txtBet.setVisible(false);

        d.hitUntil();
        String result = g.winner();
        System.out.println(result);

        if(result.equals("wbj")){
            account = account + (bet*1.5);
            lblResult.setText("You have blackjack...");
            lblResult.setVisible(true);

        }else if(result.equals("lbj")){
            account = account - bet;
            lblResult.setText("The dealer has blackjack...");
            lblResult.setVisible(true);

        }else if(result.contains("w")){
            account = account + bet;
            lblResult.setBounds(940, 185, 300, 100);
            lblResult.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 40));
            lblResult.setText("You won...");
            lblResult.setVisible(true);


        }else if(result.contains("l")){
            account = account - bet;
            lblResult.setBounds(940, 185, 300, 100);
            lblResult.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 40));
            lblResult.setText("You lost...");
            lblResult.setVisible(true);

        }else{
            lblResult.setText("Draw");
            lblResult.setVisible(true);

        }
        txtAccount.setText(f.format(account));
        //lblResult.setVisible(false);
        });
```

//////////////If it is any help here is the whole class/////////////////

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class GUI extends JFrame{

Game g;
Player p; 
Dealer d;

int aW = 1280;
int aH = 800;

Font buttonFont = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 30);

Color background = new Color(39,119,20);
Color buttonColor = new Color(204,204,0);

JLabel lblHeader = new JLabel();
JLabel lblCreater = new JLabel();
JLabel lblBet = new JLabel();
JLabel lblAccount = new JLabel();
JLabel lblResult = new JLabel();

JTextField txtBet = new JTextField();
JTextField txtAccount = new JTextField();

Button btnHit = new Button();
Button btnStay = new Button();
Button btnExit = new Button();
Button btnConfirm = new Button();

int gridX = 50;
int gridY = 50;
int gridW = 800;
int gridH = 700;

int cardSpacing = 10;
int cardTW = gridW/5;
int cardTH = gridH/2 - 50;
int cardAW = cardTW - 2*cardSpacing;
int cardAH = cardTH-2*cardSpacing;

double account;
double bet;

DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
int tPassed = 0;

public GUI(Player p, Dealer d){

    this.p = p;
    this.d = d;
    g = new Game(p, d);

    this.setSize(aW+6, aH+29);
    this.setTitle("Blackjack Java Edition");
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Board board = new Board();
    this.setContentPane(board);
    this.setLayout(null);

    lblHeader.setBounds(925, 40, 450, 80);
    lblHeader.setText("Blackjack Java Edition");
    lblHeader.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 30));
    board.add(lblHeader);

    lblCreater.setBounds(990, 80, 450, 80);
    lblCreater.setText("By Jonny Bloom");
    lblCreater.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 25));
    board.add(lblCreater);

    lblBet.setBounds(925, 210, 100, 30);
    lblBet.setText("Bet");
    lblBet.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 25));
    lblBet.setVisible(false);
    board.add(lblBet);

    lblAccount.setBounds(925, 165, 120, 30);
    lblAccount.setText("Account");
    lblAccount.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 25));
    board.add(lblAccount);

    txtBet.setBounds(980, 210, 240, 30);
    txtBet.setVisible(false);
    board.add(txtBet);

    txtAccount.setBounds(1040, 165, 180, 30);
    board.add(txtAccount);

    lblResult.setText(null);
    board.add(lblResult);

    btnHit.setBounds(925, 500, 120, 80);
    btnHit.setBackground(buttonColor);
    btnHit.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnHit.setLabel("Hit");
    btnHit.setEnabled(false);
    board.add(btnHit);

    btnHit.addActionListener(l -> {
        //System.out.println("btnHit was pressed");
        p.hit();
        System.out.println(p.h.hand);

        if(p.h.bust() == true || p.h.getValue() == 21 || p.h.hand.size() >= 5){
            d.hitUntil();
            btnHit.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    btnStay.setBounds(1100, 500, 120, 80);
    btnStay.setBackground(buttonColor);
    btnStay.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnStay.setLabel("Stay");
    btnStay.setEnabled(false);
    board.add(btnStay);

    btnStay.addActionListener(l -> {
        //System.out.println("btnStay was pressed");
        btnStay.setEnabled(false);
        btnHit.setEnabled(false);
        btnConfirm.setVisible(false);
        lblAccount.setVisible(false);
        lblBet.setVisible(false);
        txtAccount.setVisible(false);
        txtBet.setVisible(false);

        d.hitUntil();
        String result = g.winner();
        System.out.println(result);

        if(result.equals("wbj")){
            account = account + (bet*1.5);
            lblResult.setText("You have blackjack...");
            lblResult.setVisible(true);

        }else if(result.equals("lbj")){
            account = account - bet;
            lblResult.setText("The dealer has blackjack...");
            lblResult.setVisible(true);

        }else if(result.contains("w")){
            account = account + bet;
            lblResult.setBounds(940, 185, 300, 100);
            lblResult.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 40));
            lblResult.setText("You won...");
            lblResult.setVisible(true);


        }else if(result.contains("l")){
            account = account - bet;
            lblResult.setBounds(940, 185, 300, 100);
            lblResult.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 40));
            lblResult.setText("You lost...");
            lblResult.setVisible(true);

        }else{
            lblResult.setText("Draw");
            lblResult.setVisible(true);

        }
        txtAccount.setText(f.format(account));
        //lblResult.setVisible(false);
        });

    btnExit.setBounds(960, 630, 225, 80);
    btnExit.setBackground(buttonColor);
    btnExit.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnExit.setLabel("Exit");
    board.add(btnExit);

    btnExit.addActionListener(l -> {
        //System.out.println("btnExit was pressed");
        this.dispose();

    });

    btnConfirm.setBounds(975, 270, 200, 50);
    btnConfirm.setBackground(buttonColor);
    btnConfirm.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnConfirm.setLabel("Confirm");
    board.add(btnConfirm);

    btnConfirm.addActionListener(l -> {
        //System.out.println("btnConfirm was pressed");
        try{
            txtAccount.setText(f.format(Double.parseDouble(txtAccount.getText())));
            account = Double.parseDouble(txtAccount.getText());
            txtAccount.setEnabled(false);
            lblBet.setVisible(true);
            txtBet.setVisible(true);
        }catch(Exception e1){
            System.out.println(e1);
            txtAccount.setText(null);
        }

        //Second Half of Confirm Button

        try{
            txtBet.setText(f.format(Double.parseDouble(txtBet.getText())));
            bet = Double.parseDouble(txtBet.getText());
            if(bet > account || bet < 0){
                throw new Exception("Bet exceeds maximum or minimum amount");
            }
            btnHit.setEnabled(true);
            btnStay.setEnabled(true);
            txtBet.setEnabled(false);
            btnConfirm.setEnabled(false);
            for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
                p.hit();
                d.h.dealCard();
            }
            System.out.println(p.h.hand); //DISPLAY CARD HERE
            System.out.println(d.h.hand); //DISPLAY CARD HERE
        }catch(Exception e2){
            System.out.println(e2);
            txtBet.setText(null);

        }

    });
}
public class Board extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ 
        g.setColor(background);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, aW, aH);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(gridX, gridY, gridW, gridH);
        g.drawRect(gridX + gridW + 50, gridY, gridW / 3 + 75, gridH / 2 - 50);
        g.drawRect(gridX + gridW + 50, 450, gridW / 3 + 75, gridH /2 - 50);
        g.drawRect(gridX + gridW + 50, gridY, gridW / 3 + 75, (gridH / 2 - 50) / 3 - 10);


        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            g.drawRect(gridX+i*cardTW+cardSpacing, gridY+cardSpacing, cardAW, cardAH - 75);
            g.drawRect(gridX + i * cardTW + cardSpacing, gridY + cardSpacing + cardTH + 175, cardAW, cardAH - 75);

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: A Swing Timer can be thought of as a pseudo loop, which each tick of the Timer is an iteration of the loop. So, you need to establish a concept of “what needs to be done” and away to determine “how much work has been done” (ie a counter)

Comment: So, based on your stated requirements, you need a flag which determines which state should be painted, and in the Timer, flip it - just make sure you make your Timer non repeating

Comment: I think it is way too much code to demonstrate the issue. Please post [MCVE]. The long code makes the question obscure. I can only guess that you want to change the text of `lblResult` after a certain period.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void hideResult() {
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // wait 2 secons
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            // update lblResult in the edt
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    lblResult.setVisible(false);
                    board.repaint();
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```